# Operator() as a subscript (C++)

Tags: c++, operator-keyword, subscript

I use operator() as a subscript operator  this way:

```
double CVector::operator() (int i) const
{
 if (i >= 0 && i < this->size)
  return this->data[i];
 else
  return 0;
}

double& CVector::operator() (int i)
{
 return (this->data[i]);
}
```

It works when I get values, but I get an error when I try to write assign a value using

```
a(i) = 1;
```

UPD: Error text:

> Unhandled exception at 0x651cf54a
>   (msvcr100d.dll) in CG.exe: 0xC0000005:
>   Access violation reading location
>   0xccccccc0.

Comment: What error do you get?  Also: your behavior isn't consistent.  You silently fail on out-of-range values for reading and seg fault on out-of-range values for writing.

Comment: If you are writing some array type class you probably decided to do all the memory management yourself? Which means you need to define the four methods that the compiler will automatically define. If you forgot one then your going to generate invalid memory locations. Please post the constructors/destructors and assignment operator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like I said in my comment, the problem is your flawed design.  I make a 100% guarantee on one of two things:

1. The value you are passing to the assignment function is out of valid range.
2. The member `data` is pointing to invalid space in memory.

In either case, I would suggest adding:

```
#include <cassert>
```

and adding `assert(i >= 0 && i < this->size)` instead of the silent failures:

```
double CVector::operator() (int i) const
{
    assert(i >= 0 && i < this->size);
    return this->data[i];
}

double& CVector::operator() (int i)
{
    assert(i >= 0 && i < this->size);
    return (this->data[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

That's because you haven't implemented error handling in `double& CVector::operator() (int i)` like you did for the other function which overloads `()`.

Change it to:

```
double& CVector::operator() (int i)
{
 if (i >= 0 && i < this->size)
 {
  return this->data[i];
 }
 else // Whatever manner you want to gracefully exit the program
 {
  std::cout<<"Out of bounds!"<<endl;
  exit(1);
 }
}
```

You should also consider changing the error handling mechanism in the other function from `return 0;` to something more meaningful.

Answer (score 1):

> Unhandled exception at 0x651cf54a
>   (msvcr100d.dll) in CG.exe: 0xC0000005:
>   Access violation reading location
>   0xccccccc0.

`0xcc` is the MSVC uninitialized memory byte value. In other words, your problem is most likely due to accessing an uninitialized pointer or a pointer that was derived from uninitialized memory.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you do not check for out-of-range index in your `double&` version of `operator()`.

You probably cannot guarantee that `data[i]` points to a valid memory address for a large enough `i`. You should either check for out-of-range index and throw some exception or resize your vector (by allocating more memory do `data`) to be able to hold more values.